# sidekiq utilizing memory even if no workers are working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have scheduled some background tasks using sidekiq with workers concurrency of 22 
but I am seeing about 13.7% of memory consumption is happening even if none of the workers are working, Is this normal or should I have to change some configuration in sidekiq to avoid this

```
ubuntu    9331 21.8 13.7 1505656 1082988 ?     Sl   Mar06 557:08 sidekiq 2.7.5 jobs [0 of 22 busy]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

13.7% seems to be a lot of memory, but I don't know how many GB you have. (I'm pretty bad at reading top results).

However, even if all your workers are idle, Sidekiq is still running ready to process new jobs. And this consume memory.

So depending on the quantity of memory you have, it's perfectly normal.